# How to get the code coverage report using Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Is there a way to have code coverage in the JavaScript Jest testing framework, which is built on top of Jasmine?

The internal framework [does not](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/db003d5dc76b966199f8072343de1f18231d82e3/src/defaultTestResultHandler.js#L99-L103) print out the code coverage it gets. I've also tried using [Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul), [blanket](https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket), and [JSCover](https://github.com/tntim96/JSCover), but none of them work.

Comment: I'm not very into jest, but have you seen [config.collectCoverage](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#config-collectcoverage-boolean)?

Comment: istanbul works fine

Answer (score 376, accepted):

When using **Jest 21.2.1**, I can see code coverage at the command line and create a coverage directory by passing `--coverage` to the Jest script. Below are some examples:

I tend to install Jest locally, in which case the command might look like this:

`npx jest --coverage`

I assume (though haven't confirmed), that this would also work if I installed Jest globally:

`jest --coverage`

The very sparse docs are [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html#coverage)

When I navigated into the **coverage/lcov-report** directory I found an **index.html** file that could be loaded into a browser. It included the information printed at the command line, plus additional information and some graphical output.

Comment: Never use global modules. To ensure version consistency, and package presence, always use the executable in `node_modules` via `./node_modules/.bin/jest --coverage`. As long as the package is named in package.json, you can guarantee execution with the exact version of jest you expect.

Comment: How to get jest coverage only for changed files?

Comment: @ShanikaEdiriweera https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#--collectcoveragefromglob

Comment: @aagjalpankaj Yes, by specifying a `collectCoverageFrom` array as documented [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#collectcoveragefrom-array).

Answer (score 127):

UPDATE: 7/20/2018 - Added links and updated name for coverageReporters.

UPDATE: 8/14/2017 - This answer is totally outdated. Just look at the Jest docs now. They have official support and documentation about how to do this.

@hankhsiao has got a forked repo where Istanbul is working with Jest.  Add this to your dev dependencies

```
 "devDependencies": {
     "jest-cli": "git://github.com/hankhsiao/jest.git"
 }
```

Also make sure coverage is enabled in your package.json jest entry and you can also specify formats you want.  (The html is pretty bad ass).

```
 "jest": {
     "collectCoverage": true,
     "coverageReporters": ["json", "html"],
 }
```

See [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration) for [coverageReporters](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#coveragereporters-array-string) (default is  `["json", "lcov", "text"]`)

Or add `--coverage` when you invoke jest.

Comment: The coverageFormats option has been removed -- looks like json and html are both generated every time.

Comment: I use the --coverage option but absolutely nothing different happens.

Comment: It's (now) called `coverageReporters` and the default is `["json", "lcov", "text"]`. See http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#coveragereporters-array-string

Comment: dont work,   Unknown option "coverageFormats" with value ["json", "html"] was found.

Comment: Thanks, setting coverageReporters: ["json", "lcov", "text"] in jest.config.ts fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 103):

### Jan 2019: Jest version 23.6

For anyone looking into this question recently **especially if testing using `npm` or `yarn` directly**

Currently, you don't have to change the configuration options

As per [Jest official website](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#using-with-npm-scripts), you can do the following to generate coverage reports:

### 1- For npm:

**You must put `--` before passing the `--coverage` argument of Jest**

```
npm test -- --coverage
```

***if you try invoking the `--coverage` directly without the `--` it won't work***

### 2- For yarn:

You can pass the `--coverage` argument of jest directly

```
yarn test --coverage
```

Comment: How to get jest coverage only for changed files?

Comment: Changed since when? You probably want to use the `--watch` setting for this.

Comment: This answer makes a lot of assumptions about the state of ones `package.json`.

Comment: This gives me coverage for files under /test folder. Definitely not what I was looking for :D

Comment: I am late here, can I know if we can get the time to take coverage for each test case as well as the test suite to the outputFile?

Answer (score 25):

This works for me:

```
 "jest": {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": ["json", "html"]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest  --coverage"
  },
```

Run:

```
yarn/npm test
```

Comment: what is this file? Where does this JSON text go?

Comment: Should be `package.json`.

Comment: These config properties can also be included in `jest.config.js` if you have a lot of configs that you don't want cluttering up the `package.json` file.  

See Jest docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

Answer (score 15):

You can run npx jest --coverage -- path/to/your/file.spec.js
that will show coverage for affected files

If you want to view this in browser you can do as follows,

1. Go to Browser and CMD+O.
2. Navigate to your repo and search for coverage/lcov-report/index.html

Then you can visually see all the coverage areas.
[image]

You can also refer to this link below, for more information
https://dev.to/stevescruz/awesome-jest-tip-coverage-report-h5j

Comment: any idea why is this showing me "unknown %"?

Answer (score 7):

1. Check the latest Jest (v 0.22): https://github.com/facebook/jest
2. The Facebook team adds the *[Istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org/)* code coverage output as part of the coverage report and you can use it directly.
3. After executing Jest, you can get a coverage report in the console and under the root folder set by Jest, you will find the coverage report in JSON and HTML format.
4. FYI, if you install from npm, you might not get the latest version; so try the GitHub first and make sure the coverage is what you need.

Comment: The question was how to get Code coverage for Jest. That Istanbul and Jest don't work together might be true, but that doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you are having trouble with --coverage not working it may also be due to having coverageReporters enabled without 'text' or 'text-summary' being added.
From the docs: "Note: Setting this option overwrites the default values. Add "text" or "text-summary" to see a coverage summary in the console output." [Source](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#coveragereporters-array-string)

Answer (score 2):

Configure your package.json file

> "test": "jest --coverage",

[image]

Now run:

```
yarn test
```

All the test will start running and you will get the report.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add that it may be a good idea to use the [`collectCoverageFrom`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#collectcoveragefrom-array) option. Otherwise you will get a coverage of the files with actual tests for them, **excluding** those files without any tests (which might not be what you want).

Of course you can and should exclude specific files where coverage is not needed, but that's a different point.

When you use this option in your configuration, you can see during test execution that coverage is also collected for untested files, e.g.:

```
 RUNS  projects/some-lib/src/lib/directives/outside-click.directive.spec.ts (7.817 s)
 RUNS  projects/some-lib/src/lib/components/abc-icons/abc-icons.component.spec.ts (8.644 s)
 RUNS  projects/some-lib/src/lib/directives/abc-badge.directive.spec.ts (8.649 s)
Running coverage on untested files...
```

An example `jest.config.ts` would be as follows:

```
import type {Config} from 'jest';

const config: Config = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ["./src/**"],
  coverageReporters: ['html'],
  coverageDirectory: './coverage'
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score -13):

I had the same issue and I fixed it as below.

1. install yarn `npm install --save-dev yarn`
2. install jest-cli `npm install --save-dev jest-cli`
3. add this to the package.json `"jest-coverage": "yarn run jest -- --coverage"`

After you write the tests, run the command `npm run jest-coverage`. This will create a coverage folder in the root directory. */coverage/icov-report/index.html* has the HTML view of the code coverage.

Comment: There is no need to install yarn. Yarn is just different package manager to NPM

Comment: initial `--` it is just needed using npm, yarn pass all arguments to jest.

Comment: this answer is misleading