# How to get test coverage from Jest while testing React.js App?

Tags: facebook, testing, code-coverage, reactjs, jestjs

We need to check test coverage for our React.js app and *ideally* get **lcov.info** output to send to a third-party coverage tracker like [Coveralls](https://coveralls.io/) or [CodeClimate](https://codeclimate.com)

Its unclear from the [Jest API](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#content) how to get test coverage information when running tests.

There's an ***Open* Issue** on GitHub: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/101 and associated Pull Request: https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/178
but the PR still has not been merged by the Jest core team.

Is there an *alternative* way of getting coverage info that *works* ***today***?

**Note**: I'm *aware* of [@adrian-adkison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158095/adrian-adkison) suggestion in:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27479903/1148249 but [@hankhsiao's **fork**](https://github.com/hankhsiao/jest) is quite out-of-date with jest-cli since he submitted the Pull Request 2.5 months ago...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

@hankhsiao's fork has been merged. I have been using the latest https://github.com/facebook/jest and getting great results.

```
jest --coverage
```

Comment: This failed for TypeScript React project.

Answer (score 40):

```
npm test -- --coverage
```

note that extra `--` in the middle, [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#coverage-reporting)

Comment: what does that extra `--` do?

Comment: whatever follows -- are  arguments that npm will pass to the script being run, in this case probably `jest`. Will result in `jest --coverage`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I have a react app created from `create-react-app`, to get the coverage I ran `npm test -- --coverage` and it worked for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In your package.json under the script section add this piece of code -

```
test: react-scripts test --coverage
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either run jest through

```
jest --coverage
```

or you can also set `"collectCoverage"` to `true` in your jest configuration inside your package.json. This way the coverage report will be generated everytime you run jest.

Although you should know that this can increase the time taken for your tests to run significantly.

Answer (score 1):

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    ...
  },
```

run command

```
npm run test -- --watchAll=false  --coverage
```

you can also check in details

```
 /coverage/icov-report/src/...<file>.html
```

Answer (score 0):

In my **package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:coverage": "react-scripts test --coverage",
    ...
  },
```

to see test coverage

```
yarn test:coverage
```