# How to verify function that has been called or not when tap on it in jest?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

Here is the my code looks like

```
export function myComponent(user: type) {
    --------------

   return (
     <TouchableWithoutFeedback 
        testID="notificationCard"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(NEW_ROUTES.profile, { id: rawId })}
              >
        <Card style={styles.stackedCard} ></Card>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback />

  )
}
```

here I need to verify the function inside *onPress*
I don't know what to do exactly but I tried this

test.tsx

```
  const { environment, getByTestId } = renderWithNavigation(myComponent);
  const notificationCards = getByTestId("notificationCards");
  const notificationCard = getAllByTestId(notificationCards, "notificationCard");
  fireEvent.press(notificationCard[0]);
  expect(notificationCard[0]).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code coverage for Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825860/code-coverage-for-jest)

Comment: You can use spyOn `jest.spyOn(navigation, 'navigate')`