# How to check jest coverage in console?

Tags: continuous-integration, jestjs, gitlab, code-coverage

I have some jest tests and I can determine the coverage with

```
jest --coverage
```

Also see [Code coverage for Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825860/code-coverage-for-jest)

I automatically execute the tests on a build server (gitlab runner) and want that my tests **fail if the coverage is below a certain limit**.

In python there is a flag `--cov-fail-under` that can be used with pytest, e.g.

```
pytest --cov src --cov-fail-under=90 --cov-report=term
```

Unfortunately, I could not find a corresponding option for jest.

=>What is the recommended way to check the total coverage?

Should I write some extra script to evaluate the generated json coverage file or is there an easier solution like a specific reporter to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not listed under CLI-Options, but there is `coverageThreshold`, which can be used in package.json or within an extra jest configuration file:

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#coveragethreshold-object